# Kafka + Query the detailed configuration of all Topics

Tags: kafka

we have Kafka servers cluster with Kafka version 2.6 on Linux RHEL machines

machine in the cluster are - `kafka1,kafka2,kafka3`

usually we are use the following cli in order to get the detailed configuration of all Topics

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 172.78.6.5:2181 --describe
```

- 172.78.6.5 - is the zoo server IP

and the above approach is working fine

But we also try a different following approach , that should give the same results

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server="kafka1:6667" --describe
Error while executing topic command : The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
[2021-09-02 11:19:02,486] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS
(kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

but above cli complained about - `Error while executing topic command : The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS`

is above cli - is valid approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the command you've given is valid, **but** only for certain version of the **broker**, not the cli.